# Getting error while using ngRoute in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-route

I am getting the following error while using Angular.js in my app.

Error:

```
angular.js:38Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.6/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=Error%3A%20%…oudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.4.6%2Fangular.min.js%3A41%3A35)
```

I am providing my code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="app">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>DEMO</title>
<link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.6/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.6/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="angularuirouter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
<a href="#/visitplace">I want to go for a trip</a>
<div ng-view></div>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

script.js:

```
"use strict";
var app = angular.module( "app",[],function( $routeProvider ) {
  $routeProvider.when( "/visitplace", {
    templateUrl: "placetovisit.html",
    controller: "TourCoordinatorCtrl",
    resolve: {
      "accommodation": function( $q, $timeout ) {
        var myFriend = $q.defer();
        $timeout(function(){
          myFriend.resolve({
            hotelName: function( ) {
              return "My Friend's friend's hotel";
            },
            roomNo: function( ) {
              return "404";
            }
          });
        },5000);
        return myFriend.promise;
      }
    }
  });
} );
app.controller( "TourCoordinatorCtrl", function( $scope, accommodation ) {
  $scope.name = "Shidhin";
  $scope.place = "Switzerland";
  $scope.hotel = accommodation.hotelName( );
  $scope.roomno = accommodation.roomNo( );
} );
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: try setting route in `.config` instead of module definition

Comment: Try injecting ``$routeProvider`` to module definition like ``var app = angular.module( "app",[$routeProvider]``

Comment: During development always use non-minified version of Angular. It gives exact error detail with line numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't injected the ngRoute module into your app. That is why you are getting an injector error.

You must define your app like this (for example):

```
var app = angular.module( "app", ['ngRoute']);
```

Then configure the route provider.

Answer (score 1):

Missing ngRoute injection on your main module.

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute'])
```

Answer (score 0):

angular.module("app",[]).config(["$stateProvider","$urlRouterProvider",
function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider)
{
url routeprovider
}])

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers are correct but this can also happen when you do NOT include a Controller file. Example below shows at line 60 I had commented out the controller file but at line 13 I was actually referencing a AppCtrl. If I uncomment the line 60 the error goes away.

[image]

Here is what you would see on the console:

[image]